# Ajax properly executes INSERT INTO one table but not on another table... weird

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, sqlsrv

I have an ajax php file with two main INSERT queries... we insert an order first and then we insert different lines within that order. Im able to properly insert the order but unable to insert the lines in the same database. So one query is working and the second one is not. The server runs in an EC2 instance in AWS

Tried everything I know of... even double checking sql parameters to see if something in MSSQL prevents the lines from being properly stored.

```
<?php
     session_start();

     if(!isset($_SESSION['idCompany'])){

         $login=false;
         echo ' <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/">';
         return;
     }   


     if(!ini_get('date.timezone') )                                                                          
    {
       date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    }

    $idItem=$_POST['articulo'];
    $quantity=1;

    $uid = "user";
    $pwd = "password";
    $serverName = "localhost";

    // Array DB-Conn 
    $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
    "PWD"=>$pwd,
    "Database"=>"CompanyApp");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Error.</br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    // QUERY TO SHOW ACTUAL USER
    $sql = "select * from OrdersLCompany where control='3' and idCompany='".$_SESSION['idCompany']."' and serie='D'";

    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );


    $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql), $params, $options);
    //CHECK IF USER HAS ANY ORDERS
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);

    $order = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);


    function mssql_addslashes($data) { 
        $data = str_replace("'", "''", $data); 
        return $data; 
    } 


    if($row_count==0)
    { 
        //CREATE ORDER
        $sql = "select isnull(max(number),0)+1 from OrdersLCompany where idCompany='".$_SESSION['idCompany']."'";

        $params = array();
        $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

        $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql), $params, $options);        
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);

        $number=$row[0];

        //INSERT ORDER
        $sql_insert="INSERT INTO OrdersLCompany (serie, number, idCompany, fecha, control) 
                    VALUES  ('D','".$number."','".$_SESSION['idCompany']."','".date('Ymd H:i:s')."',3)";

        $query_ins = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_insert), $params, $options);     

        if( $query_ins === false )
        {
            echo "Error al insertar un order nuevo.</br>";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }else{          
            //ORDER JUST CREATED SO LINE IS GOING TO BE 1

                $sql_price_stock = "select priceLO, CASE WHEN stock>0 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END, Abreviación from Items_tarifa_stock
                    left join Items on Items.idItem=Items_Tarifa_Stock.idItem
                    right join Items_CompanyApp on Items_CompanyApp.idItem=Items.idItem 
                     where Items_tarifa_stock.idItem='".$idItem."'";

                $query_line = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_price_stock), $params, $options);
                $price_stock = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_line);

                $price=$price_stock[0];
                $stock=$price_stock[1];
                $abrev=mssql_addslashes($price_stock[2]);

                if($price=="null" or $price<="0"){
                    echo "5";
                    return;
                }
                if($stock=="1")
                {
                    $sql_insert_line="INSERT INTO OrderslCompany_lines (serie, number, line, order, idCompany, idItem, description, quantity, cost, total, stock) 
                            VALUES  ('D','".$number."','1','1','".$_SESSION['idCompany']."','".$idItem."','".$abrev."','1','".$price."','".$price."','1')";
                    $query_ins_line = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_insert_line), $params, $options);       

                    if( $query_ins_line === false )
                    {
                        echo "Error inserting line.</br>";
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }               
                }else{
                    echo "No stock";
                }
        }

        // Close conn. 
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $query);
        sqlsrv_close( $conn);       
        return;

    }else{

        //Check order and line...       
        $sql = "select number from OrdersLCompany where control='3' and idCompany='".$_SESSION['idCompany']."' and serie='D'";

        $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql), $params, $options);
        $order = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);

        $numberl=$order[0];

        //Aquí saber la última line que hay que meter.
        $sql = "select isnull(max(line),0)+1 from OrderslCompany_lines where number='".$numberl."' and idCompany='".$_SESSION['idCompany']."' and serie='D'";
        $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql), $params, $options);
        $orderl = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);       
        $line=$orderl[0];

        $sql_price_stock = "select priceLO, CASE WHEN stock>0 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END, Abreviación from Items_tarifa_stock
            left join Items on Items.idItem=Items_Tarifa_Stock.idItem
            right join Items_CompanyApp on Items_CompanyApp.idItem=Items.idItem 
             where Items_tarifa_stock.idItem='".$idItem."'";

        $query_line = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_price_stock), $params, $options);
        $price_stock = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_line);

        $price=$price_stock[0];
        $stock=$price_stock[1];
        $abrev=mssql_addslashes($price_stock[2]);

        if($price=="null" or $price<="0"){
                echo "5";
                return;
            }

        if($stock=="1")
        {
            //if item exists in the order we add up.
            $sql_consulta_productos_order="Select quantity FROM OrderslCompany_lines where number='".$numberl."' and idCompany='".$_SESSION['idCompany']."' and serie='D' and cost<>0 and idItem='".$idItem."'";
            $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_consulta_productos_order));
            $exists = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);                                   
            $exists=$exists[0]; 

            //If item exists we update same line
            if($exists>=1){
                if($exists>=150)
                {
                    echo "NOMORE";
                    return;
                }

                //Add 1 unit to existing items. Increment quantity, price y total.
                $sql_actualizar_line="UPDATE OrderslCompany_lines SET quantity=quantity+1, total=convert(float,cost)*(quantity+1) WHERE number='".$numberl."' and idCompany='".$_SESSION['idCompany']."' and serie='D' and cost<>0 and idItem='".$idItem."'";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_actualizar_line));
                if( $stmt === false )
                {
                    echo "Error.</br>";
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }

            }else{
                if($quantity>=150)
                {
                    echo "NOMORE";

                }
                $sql_insert_line="INSERT INTO OrderslCompany_lines (serie, number, line, order, idCompany, idItem, description, quantity, cost, total, stock) 
                    VALUES  ('D','".$numberl."','".$line."','".$line."','".$_SESSION['idCompany']."','".$idItem."','".$abrev."','1','".$price."','".$price."','1')";
                $query_ins_line = sqlsrv_query( $conn, utf8_decode($sql_insert_line), $params, $options);       

                if( $query_ins_line === false )
                {
                    echo "Error inserting line within the order.</br>";
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }               
            }
        }else{
            echo "No stock";
        }


        if( $query === false )
        {
            echo "Error.</br>";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        $marcadores ="";
        // show result


        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "-".$row[0];
        }


        // Close conn. 
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $query);
        sqlsrv_close( $conn);
    }



?>
```

Comment: You *really* need to fix those huge injection issues first and start parametrising your code. Learn from [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: What error does your `die()` statement print out? Does `user` have insert permissions on the `OrderslCompany_lines` table? Also, your technique for coming up with the next order number creates a race condition: if you get two (or more) orders coming in simultaneously they could get the same order number.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning die() throws no error and user is the superadmin of the mssql instance.... in fact the previous query (the one for creating the order) works as expected (let aside the race condition... need to recode that...) but the next insert won´t work and just cannot figure out what the problem is... its exactly the same code used in another server folder for with a different database where everything works...  really weird...

Comment: Possibly the ODBC connection is getting left in a funny state between SQL statements. I'd be inclined to wrap each of your SQL statements (select, insert, update) in its own `sqlsrv_connect` and `sqlsrv_close` and make use of [Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-pooling-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server) so that the connection gets properly reset before each statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should consider the following:

- Use parameterized statements and do not use `mssql_addslashes()` function to sanitize your input. With PHP Driver for SQL Server, function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.
- Always check the result from `sqlsrv_query()` execution.
- Use `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` with `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` to access the the data as a numeric array.
- Don't use `utf8_decode()` to encode the SQL statement.

I made some changes in your script, so you may try to test with the next example (but it only creates the order and the order items):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['idCompany'])) {
    $login = false;
    echo ' <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/">';
    return;
}   
if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
}

$idItem = $_POST['articulo'];
$quantity = 1;

// Connection
$uid = "user";
$pwd = "password";
$serverName = "localhost";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID"=>$uid,
    "PWD"=>$pwd,
    "Database"=>"CompanyApp"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false ) {
    echo "Error.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// QUERY TO SHOW ACTUAL USER
$sql = "select * from OrdersLCompany where control='3' and idCompany=? and serie='D'";
$params = array($_SESSION['idCompany']);
$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params, $options);
if ($query === false) {
    echo "Error.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//CHECK IF USER HAS ANY ORDERS
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
if ($row_count == 0) { 
    // CREATE ORDER
    $sql = "select isnull(max(number),0)+1 from OrdersLCompany where idCompany=?";
    $params = array($_SESSION['idCompany']);
    $options = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params, $options);        
    if ($query === false) {
        echo "Error.</br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
    $number = $row[0];

    // INSERT ORDER
    $sql_insert = 
        "INSERT INTO OrdersLCompany (serie, number, idCompany, fecha, control) 
        VALUES ('D', ?, ?, ?, 3)";
    $params = array($number, $_SESSION['idCompany'], date('Ymd H:i:s'));
    $options = array();
    $query_ins = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_insert, $params, $options);     
    if( $query_ins === false ) {
        echo "Error al insertar un order nuevo.</br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    // ORDER JUST CREATED SO LINE IS GOING TO BE 1
    $sql_price_stock = 
        "select 
            priceLO, 
            CASE WHEN stock>0 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END, 
            Abreviación 
        from Items_tarifa_stock
        left join Items on Items.idItem=Items_Tarifa_Stock.idItem
        right join Items_CompanyApp on Items_CompanyApp.idItem=Items.idItem 
        where Items_tarifa_stock.idItem=?";
    $params = array($idItem);
    $options = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $query_line = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_price_stock, $params, $options);
    if ($query_line === false) {
        echo "Error al insertar un order nuevo.</br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $price_stock = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_line, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
    $price1 = $price_stock[0];
    $price2 = $price_stock[0];
    $stock = $price_stock[1];
    $abrev = $price_stock[2];
    if ($price == "null" or $price <= "0") {
        echo "5";
        return;
    }
    if ($stock == "1") {
        $sql_insert_line = 
            "INSERT INTO OrderslCompany_lines (serie, number, line, order, idCompany, idItem, description, quantity, cost, total, stock) 
            VALUES  ('D', ?, '1', '1', ?, ?, ?, '1', ?, ?, '1')";
        $params = array($number, .$_SESSION['idCompany'], $idItem, $abrev, $price1, $price2);
        $options = array();
        $query_ins_line = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_insert_line, $params, $options);       
        if( $query_ins_line === false ) {
            echo "Error inserting line.</br>";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }               
    } else {
        echo "No stock";
    }

    return;

} else {

    // ... Your other PHP code here

}

?>
```